# AWS API Gateway Overwriting Integration Request Mapping Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

It appears that when I send a body with a POST request my template mapping is getting overwritten by the payload.

I have an API gateway resource invoking a Lambda function. The Lambda function is simple, it just echoes what it receives.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    context.succeed({event: event});
};
```

This Lambda function, called echo, is invoking the Lambda function through a POST. The POST method has an integration request mapping template (which is straight from the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-example-json-mapping-template)):

```
{
    "name" : "$input.params('name')",
    "body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

When I make a request *WITHOUT* a body I get back the response I expect:

```
curl -XPOST https://foo.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/echo?name=foo

{"event":{"name":"foo","body":{}}
```

However, when I make a request *WITH* a body the template mapping no longer works:

```
curl -XPOST https://foo.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/echo?name=foo -d '{"text": "Say goodbye to your template mapping"}'

{"event":{"text":"Say goodbye to your template mapping"}
```

How can I ensure my template mapping applies when a body is present in the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping templates are bound to a request by the content type of the request. In this case the template mapping was for the content type 'application/json'. By including the `Content-Type: application/json` header in the request the mapping template is applied.

This returns the expected result:

```
curl -XPOST https://qb9p3d1ovf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/echo?name=foo -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"text": "Say goodbye to your template mapping"}'

{"event":{"name":"foo","body":{"text":"Say HELLO to your template mapping"}}
```

Comment: Thank you. So. Much. Seriously.